# MVVM ViewModel creating and binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I was going to create this with windows forms but was told that wpf mvvm would be better.  I am new to c# and have been researching mvvm and wpf.

I am now working on my viewmodel to work with both the view and the model.  There is no database.

---

My problem:

how do I correctly bind the view to the viewmodel.  I am missing a itemssource or localsource code somewhere in my xaml but I also do not understand how the itemsource works.  Where in the viewmodel is the itemsource declared and how.  I have been googling for a good answer but still have not found one that makes it click for me.

I also know there is an INotifyChange type property and i have seen some code examples but dont fully understand it, it just has not clicked for me.

---

Currently:

I have a view created in xaml which is the first code below.  I then created a class for a scan which is the second group of code below in c# (i know the get set methods could be improved but i was following a tutorial).

The user with the scan gun is not going to be looking at the screen when they are scanning.  I want to be able to go in order so first scan fills in the first text box, second scan fills the second text box and if needed they will fill in the count.

---

Extra info:

The bottom part (dataview) is a temp table for showing previous scans but I can figure that our later.  Most important part is being able to get the scans and do something with them.

The scans will be keyboardwedge (sends characters like being typed w/ an enter key at the end) but later i am planning on making them serial com port so this program can run in the background.

Note:  I know i gave a lot of detail that is probobly not needed for the small current problem but just wanted to be clear.

```
<Window x:Class="ScanningV2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="700">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Height="100" Background="#FFFFFF" Margin="2,2,2,2">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150"></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="Scan" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="2,2,2.2,2" />
            <Label Content="Operator Barcode" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
            <Label Content="MO/Task Barcode" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
            <Label Content="Quantity" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="350,20,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,50,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Scan" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="120" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="200,50,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Scan" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="120" />
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="350,50,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="Scan" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="20" Width="120" />

            <!--            <ListView Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="curScans" Background="Aqua" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Margin="1.8,0,-0.4,0">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Scanner" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=curScanNum}" Width="150" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Operator" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=curOperator}" Width="200" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Task" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=curTask}" Width="200"/>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView> -->
        </Grid>
        <ListView x:Name="pastScans" Background="#2FFFFFFF" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Scanner" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ScannerNum}" Width="100" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Operator barcode" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Operator}" Width="150" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="MO/Task barcode" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Task}" Width="150" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Date" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ScanDate}" Width="100" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Time" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ScanTime}" Width="100" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Quantity" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Quantity}" Width="100" />
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

    </DockPanel>

</Window>
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ScanningV2
{
    class scan
    {
        //Member variables
        private string operatorCode;
        public string OperatorCode
        {
            get { return operatorCode; }
            set { operatorCode = value; }
        }

        private string taskCode;
        public string TaskCode
        {
            get { return taskCode; }
            set { taskCode = value; }
        }

        private int count;
        public int Count
        {
            get { return count; }
            set { count = value; }
        }

        private DateTime scanDateTime;
        public DateTime ScanDateTime
        {
            get { return scanDateTime; }
            set { scanDateTime = value; }
        }

        //Default Constructor
        public scan()
        {
            operatorCode = null;
            taskCode = null;
            count = 0;
        }

        //Overload Constructor
        public scan(string OperCode, string TaskMOCode, int CountNum)
        {
            operatorCode = OperCode;
            taskCode = TaskMOCode;
            count = CountNum;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your scan class needs to inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged, and each instance should be in an observable collection.  It's the observable collection that should be created in your VM and bound to the ListView control's item source property.  Getting the c# property generating snippet will save your LIFE in terms of refactoring your 'scan' class!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to set an instance of your view-model class as the DataContext of your view. I usually do this in the code-behind of a view, so in your MainWindow.xaml.cs you would do the following:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = new Scan();
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that your view won't be able to detect changes unless you notify it. That's the point of the INotifyPropertyChanged interface:

```
class Scan : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // Implementing the INotifyPropertyChanged interface:
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    // A utility method to make raising the above event a little easier:
    protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    // Then, notify the view about changes whenever a property is set:
    private string operatorCode;
    public string OperatorCode
    {
        get { return operatorCode; }
        set { operatorCode = value; RaisePropertyChanged("OperatorCode"); }
    }
}
```

In your MainWindow.xaml, you can bind to that property:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding OperatorCode}" />
```

Now, whenever you set a new value for OperatorCode, your view will be notified so it can fetch and display the new value.

For ItemsSources, any IEnumerable will do - a List, an array... however, if you want the view to be notified whenever your collection changes, you'll have to use a class that implements INotifyCollectionChanged, such as ObservableCollection.

So, you create a bindable property in your view-model:

```
private ObservableCollection<string> names;
public ObservableCollection<string> Names
{
    get { return names; }
    set { names = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Names"); }
}
```

And you bind to that from within your view:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Names}" />
```

Minor point: in C#, class names are usually written in CamelCase. Also, personally I prefer giving each view-model class a ViewModel postfix, so you can quickly see which classes are meant to be view-models. I try to match their name to the name of the view they belong to, so instead of 'scan', I would call this one 'MainWindowViewModel'.

Comment: Pieter, thank you, this is a great going off point.  A lot of your little comments put together what i was missing in most of the other readings.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind any of that to any WPF UI elements because your code is too java-like.

You need to use [Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx) the C# way.

change all your `get()` and `set()` methods to real properties.

Comment: Thank you HighCore for the start.  I have changed them correctly I believe.